# How to connect more I2C sensors on top of a RPI shield

Tags: sensor, i2c, raspbian-stretch, wiring, breadboard

I'm struggling with a problem, how to connect more sensors on top of this raspberry shield => https://sixfab.com/product/raspberry-pi-nb-iot-shield/

The shields schematic can be found here and it shows how the I2C pinout works =>
https://github.com/sixfab/RPI-NB-IoT-Shield/blob/master/hardware/rpi_nb-iot_sch.PDF

I have a [Adafruit CCS811](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3566) sensor breakout board I would like to add on top of the shield. I tried to connect like shown in the pictures below, but the LED on the sensor breakout wont lit, and my `i2cdetect` does not show any added addresses. I'm wondering is my wiring correct and am I able to see the new added devices trough `i2cdetect`?

If I need to give the sensor 3.3v, where could I take it from, since the shield does not give any 3.3v pinout?

Sorry for possibly stupid question, my embedded is not very strong.

[image]

Comment: The most likely problem is incorrect wiring between the shield I2C header and the breadboard.  I'd guess the LED should light once power is applied.  Test by just supplying power and ground without using the shield.

Comment: Tested with an Arduino Uno, got reading from sensors, but LED does not lit up.

Comment: Okay, so put it back in place and check SDA and SCL are correctly placed.

Comment: Tested with Raspberry without the shield. Raspberry freezed and now only a red LED is showing when I power on. Can't connect through SSH.

Comment: That sounds like an incorrect connection and does not sound good.

Answer (score 0):

I just google out some solution but not sure, maybe this kind of I2C [shield](https://store.ncd.io/product/i2c-shield-for-raspberry-pi-3-pi2-with-outward-facing-i2c-port/) might be helpful but you have to do some amount of soldering so that it will be fixed easily or other than that, this [I2C extension board](https://store.ncd.io/product/i2c-cross-over-adapter-with-pass-through-for-i2c-cable-reversing-i2c-mini-module/) can also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From your fuzzy picture you forgot to connect the ground. Connect that your red led will work. You can take the SCL and SDA lines and extend them to other I2C components. Be careful the lines do not get to long and that you have the bus terminated with pull up resistors in the 3K range because of the 3V3 in place of the more common 4.7K recommended with 5V logic.